# Is there any way by which I can add more than 400 entries in the DataTable or DataView while using geomaps, google charts

Tags: d3.js, datatable, google-visualization, geomap

Is there any way by which I can add ***more*** than 400 entries in the **DataTable** or **DataView** while using **geomaps** from google charts?

This is the note that is displayed on [the geomap page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap#data-format)-

> Note: A map can display a maximum of 400 entries; if your DataTable or
> DataView holds more than 400 rows, only the first 400 will be shown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't see a way around the limit. _maybe_ use a second chart with everything set to transparent, except the markers, and overlay the original chart...?

Comment: @WhiteHat can you give some more details on how to do that. Sorry, i'm new to this.